Java Cucumber doesn't run any scenario
I created a branch from an already existing git project about web testing in java, selenium, gherkin and cucumber.
Everything on it works for all my colleagues but it doesn't for me.
I run a test scenario but it gives me:
[17:35:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:35:29] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[17:35:30] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://*ip*
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
[17:35:34] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[17:35:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[17:35:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Given this, I understand that it runs the start and end procedures but for some reason, it doesn't run any command on the .feature file. It runs the same as if the file was completely empty.
So far I've tried different webdriver and chrome versions, reinstalling cucumber extension, moving the file to upper folders...
What really doesn't make sense is that, it works once in every 20 attempts I try to run the test scenario without changing anything.

Sounds like something is crashing in the startup code before the tests ran. Perhaps the exception is swallowed? Hard to say without sufficient detail to reproduce the problem.

@M.P.Korstanje what information would you need?

Enough information to reproduce the problem. It might help to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
